# starting oracle database automatically

Tags: boot, fedora

I am using Fedora 8 and Oracle 10g Express Edition.

Every time I start my fedora I have to click on start database.

How can I add startdb.sh to startup so that it automatically executes when Fedora starts?

I have tried adding the path to [/etc/rc.d/rc.local](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/auto-execute-shell-script-on-startup-294891/) but it still doesn't work.

> ./usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/config/scripts/startdb.sh

I have even tried to add this script in [/etc/init.d/oracle](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Oracle-9i-Fedora-3-Install-HOWTO/sect_08.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Run-level Startup script for the Oracle Instance and Listener
#
# chkconfig: 345 91 19
# description: Startup/Shutdown Oracle listener and instance

ORA_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0.1.0"
ORA_OWNR="oracle"

# if the executables do not exist -- display error

if [ ! -f $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart -o ! -d $ORA_HOME ]
then
        echo "Oracle startup: cannot start"
        exit 1
fi

# depending on parameter -- startup, shutdown, restart 
# of the instance and listener or usage display 

case "$1" in
    start)
        # Oracle listener and instance startup
        echo -n "Starting Oracle: "
        su - $ORA_OWNR -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"
        su - $ORA_OWNR -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart
        touch /var/lock/subsys/oracle
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    stop)
    # Oracle listener and instance shutdown
        echo -n "Shutdown Oracle: "
        su - $ORA_OWNR -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"
        su - $ORA_OWNR -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/oracle
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    reload|restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop|restart|reload"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

and even this doesn't work.

startdb.sh is located at /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/config/scripts/startdb.sh

Thanks.

Comment: @BillThor, harrymc I'll try it tomorrow in my college and let you know. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

These articles may help:

[Automating Database Startup and Shutdown on Linux](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/AutomatingDatabaseStartupAndShutdownOnLinux.php)
[Automating Database Startup and Shutdown on Other Operating Systems](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10812_06/chapter2.htm#CHDBGJAC)

Answer (score 1):

Chect the execute permission on /etc/init.d/oracle.  Test it by running `/etc/init.d/oracle start`,  It should try to start oracle for you.

Check /etc/oratab has an entry for for your database flagged Y in the autostart column.

Check that you have the rc.d links using `ls /etc/rc?.d/*oracle`.  There should be several entries for K19oracle and S91oracle.  If not run `chkconfig /etc/init.d/oracle` and recheck.